# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to retrieve records from my database but I always end up getting an invalid argument error in the @foreach. My syntax looks correct and I cannot find where the problem is. Kindly help out.

role.blade.php

```
  <div class="box-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th></th> -->
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Company ID</th>
        <th>Role Type</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @foreach ($data as $datas)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $datas->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $datas->company_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $datas->role_type }}</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

controller.php

```
public function roles(){
        $data = DB::select('select * from roles');
        return view('admin.roles', ['data'=>'$data']);
    }
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/roles', 'mainController@roles');
```

Comment: print your `$data` variable before foreach loop

Comment: How can I do that @prakashtank

Comment: Always do print_r($data); whenever you are stuck while looping and check what exactly it is printing dude :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to iterate over string, so change this:

```
'data'=>'$data'
```

To:

```
'data' => $data
```

Comment: Thanks. I felt like a dumbass when I saw this error. Solved my issue out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `get()` method to get data from database. Remove single quote from view function `$data`, passing data with single quote will consider as a string not an array.

```
public function roles(){
    $data = DB::select('select * from roles')->get();
    return view('admin.roles', ['data'=>$data]);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to add `get()` to a raw query.

Answer (score 0):

It would be giving an error because the `$data` would be empty.

So you would need to check if the variable is set and not empty.

In you blade template file, you would need to put an `if` statement as show below:

```
.....
</tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      @if (isset($data) && !empty($data))

        @foreach ($data as $datas)
        <tr>
          <td>{{ $datas->id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $datas->company_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ $datas->role_type }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

      @endif  
      </tbody>
.....
```

[More about blade templates control structures](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#control-structures)

Comment: for each "singular" you are treating it as a "plural"? Maybe is a better practice to do it backwards: for each "plural" as "singular". happy coding...